Does the area Apollonian Gasket go to zero?
Does the total area of circles of Apollonian Gasket approach the area of the main circle?
Edit  Original question was: Covering circle with circles
The unit square can be trivially be covered by squares of geometric progression like $$3\sum_{k=1} \frac{1}{4^k}$$
Is there any covering of a circle by circles that are fully contained in the main circle?
but a better phrasing of the question should use Apollonian Gasket, thanks to comment by @CosmicOscillator

I feel like circle packing problems would be a lot less interesting if there were (if overlap is not allowed; the problem is trivial if it is).

Maybe you're thinking of something like the Apollonian Gasket?

@CosmicOscillator : does the area of circles approach the area of the main circle?

@jimjim Yes, the area does seem to approach that of the main circle. See here.

@CosmicOscillator thank you , wish that was answer so that I could accept it
